# Getting "Reading null" when trying to write to a file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a 2D array to a text file, and when I try to write to it, I keep getting "Reading null"

The user inputs 2 dimensional points into an array that can store up to 100 points.

```
Point[] A = new Point[100];

System.out.println("Enter index: ");
int i = in.nextInt(); //validate
System.out.print("Enter integers x, y to replace: ");
int x = in.nextInt();
int y = in.nextInt();
A[i] = new Point(x, y);
```

Then I try to print the points to the file

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("Project.txt"); 
for (int k=0; k<A.length ; k++){
    p.println(Arrays.deepToString(A));
}
p.close();
```

Then it does this.

opening Project.txtReading null

It's like it doesn't know the file exists, but I've made the file already, and it's in the same folder as this java file. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please provide a small runnable example? And tell us which libraries you're using (if you use one/some).

Comment: _"but I've made the file already, and it's in the same folder as this java file"_ - Do you mean "java file" as in a compiled `.jar` file, or as in development `.java` files? If it's the latter case, the `Project.txt` file should be in the root of your project, not with the `.java` files.

Comment: @Tom I have made an [mcve] (MCVE) that, I believe, will be equivalent to what Johnny123 is trying to do. Here is the link: https://gist.github.com/AlmightyR/20679aa4fdda43bb4369 --- Also, if this MCVE is what Johnny123 intends; then I have no problems running it, *even with the file not being created manually* (it's created automatically), and, at a glance, the output seems ok as well.